# How to Hide Field Based on Current User Role in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I have column *Status* (0= Default, 1=Accepted, 2=Rejected), when first creating this list
I want to hidden this field and filling it with default value (0).

On edit form, I want to hide this column from updating if user role is not *HelpDesk*.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first requirement, you could use [SPUtility.js](http://sputility.codeplex.com/) (full disclosure this is a library I maintain). You would basically put [some JavaScript in a Content Editor Web Part](http://sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation) on your NewForm.aspx page:

```
SPUtility.GetSPField('Status').Hide();
```

If you want to change the value (if you don't have a default specified in your list settings) then you could do:

```
SPUtility.GetSPField('Status').SetValue('Default').Hide();
```

The second requirement is a bit tougher. You don't really specify how the user gets a role of "HelpDesk" (profile property? SharePoint group?). Depending on how it is setup, you may be able to use an AJAX call to the SharePoint webservices to check their security. Or you could write a custom webpart that validates their role and then emits some JavaScript.

Comment: Thx Kit, I have more question, how to hide default toolbar in SP can this script do that also ?

Comment: The toolbar that has attach file and spellcheck? SPUtility.js doesn't but you could hide it with some css: table.ms-toolbar { display: none }

Answer (score 0):

Use [Infowise Smart List Lite](http://infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=SmartListLite), the free version of our Smart List Pro product. Your requirement is just one of its many features.

Comment: That web part looks cool! I'll have to download it sometime. Field validation is something I want to put in SPUtility.js. :D